# Payment method section in admin redirected to home page

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

We have one payment module appmerce_migs installed in magento & whenever we click on Payment Method tab in admin in magento then it is redirected to home page. If we disable this module then working fine.

The same module we have in local & there everything working fine.

We checked in var/log but there is nothing.

What is the issue! Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Can anyone please give a flash? Any sort of hint? There is no any log generated so we are very confused on how to solve :) where to look :) etc...etc...

Comment: Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are running ssl on live server. It may be possible that your module is not using ssl. This could be one of the reason of redirection to homepage.

Comment: Hi Abhinav,  Thank you for your valuable reply :) We are checking that...& yes there is https in admin so removing that & reply to you after 2 3 minutes.

Comment: Hi Abhinav, Nope, still no luck :(  Any other suggestion please? Also can you please tell us how to check any module is compatible to https or not?